# MySQL count selected rows in one table to update value in another table

Tags: mysql

I have created a table ("texts" table) for storing ocr text from scanned documents. The table now has 100,000 + records. It stores a separate record for each page in the document. I set up the table originally so it stored the documents' title and its location against each record, which was obviously bad design as the info was duplicated for many records. I have subsequently created a separate table which now only stores one record for each document ("documents" table). The original table still contains a record for each page in the document, but the only columns now are the ocr text and the id of the document record in the documents table.

The documents table has a column "total_pages". I am trying to update this value using the following query:

```
UPDATE documents SET total_pages=(SELECT Count(*) from texts where texts.docs_id=documents.id)
```

This just seems to take forever to execute and I have had to crash out of it on a couple of occasions. There are over 8000 records in the documents table.

I have tested the query by limiting it to just one document

```
UPDATE documents SET total_pages=(SELECT Count(*) from texts where texts.docs_id=documents.id and documents.id=1)
```

This works eventually with just one record, but it takes a very long time to execute. I am guessing that my full query needs a bit of optimization! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: After going through all that trouble to normalize the table, don't destroy your good work by adding a denormalized page count to the master table. You'll have a much better application if you just query the page count as needed - no worries about the count being mangled or out of date. As long as the `texts.docs_id` column is indexed the count query will be blazingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE documents
    SET total_pages = (SELECT Count(*)
                       from texts
                       where texts.docs_id = documents.id)
```

For performance, you want an index on `texts(docs_id)`.  That will probably fix your performance problem.  In fact, it might make it unnecessary to store this value in the master table.

If you do decide to store the count, be sure that you keep the value up-to-date.  That would typically require a trigger to handle inserts and dates (and perhaps updates, if `doc_id` changes).

Comment: Sorry I should have said the texts table is indexed. But still the query is incredibly slow. Does anyone have any ideas as to how could improve performance?